# Find index of largest Integer

Tags: list, haskell, integer

I'm dabbling in some Haskell and have stumbled upon a bump in the road

I want to write a function that an AI uses to choose a row in a simple board game. The board in said game is represented by a list of integers. Like this:

```
board = [1,2,3,4,5]
```

The index + 1 of the numbers in the row on the board and the `Int` itself is the number of pieces left on said row. How I aim to make this function work is by first to find the largest number in the list and then return (index + 1) of this number in the form of an `IO Int`.

This is where I'm struggling since I can't seem to find any good answer to this online

This is what I'm working with so far:

```
-- Returns index of row with largest number along the number itself
aiHelper :: Board -> (Int, Int)
aiHelper xs = maximumBy (comparing fst) (zip xs [1..])

-- Returns row with largest number as IO Int
aiRow :: Board -> IO Int
aiRow xs = do
              let y = snd $ aiHelper xs
              return $ y
```

I'm not quite sure if this code does what I'm looking for, and is there an easier and cleaner solution to my code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can simplify the code like this:

```
aiRow :: Board -> IO Int
aiRow xs = return $ snd $ aiHelper xs
```

Or, by making an [Eta reduction](https://wiki.haskell.org/Eta_conversion), to this:

```
aiRow :: Board -> IO Int
aiRow = return . snd . aiHelper
```

But, really, you don't need to return `IO Int`. Why not just the following?

```
aiRow :: Board -> Int
aiRow = snd . aiHelper
```

At this point, however, you're probably below the [Fairbairn threshold](https://wiki.haskell.org/Fairbairn_threshold).

Comment: Nice, hadn't heard the term "Fairbairn threshold" before.

Comment: very nice answer indeed

Comment: My favorite example of something exceeding the Fairbairn threshold (almost) only because few people would think of the most efficient way to do it is `Data.Sequence.intersperse`. I'm quite proud of that one.

Answer (score 1):

After Mark's proposal, `aiRow` now does so little on its own that you might as well combine it with `aiHelper`:

```hs
maximumIndex :: Ord a => [a] -> Int
maximumIndex = fst . maximumBy (comparing snd) . zip [1..]
```

(Switching `fst` and `snd`.)